# Flutter, FieldValue.removeArray() is not working

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to remove the elements from a list in the firestore db, but it's not working. What I find odd is that FieldValue.arrayUnion() and FieldValue.delete() works fine. Why is FieldValue.arrayRemove() the only one not working? Thanks.

#### Db service

```
 import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
    import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
    import "package:innovative_world/models/list_model.dart";

    class DatabaseService {
      // Collection Reference
      CollectionReference listCollection = Firestore.instance.collection("list");

      // Get current users id
      final String uid;
      DatabaseService({this.uid});

      // Set data to firestore db
      Future setUserData(List<String> list) async {
        return await listCollection.document(uid).setData({ 
          "list": list
        });
      }

      // DOES NOT WANT TO REMOVE ELEMENTS
      Future deleteListArr(int index) async {
        return await listCollection.document(uid)
          .updateData({ "list": FieldValue.arrayRemove([index]) });
      }

      // UserList snapshot
      UserList _userListFromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
        return UserList(
          uid: uid, 
          list: snapshot.data["list"].cast<String>().toList()
          ); 
      } 
      // Stream for user's to do list
      Stream<UserList> get userListStream {
        return listCollection.document(uid).snapshots()
          .map(_userListFromSnapshot);
      }
    }
```

#### Home

```
  import "package:flutter/material.dart";
    import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
    import "package:innovative_world/services/auth_service.dart";
    import "package:innovative_world/models/list_model.dart";
    import 'package:innovative_world/services/database_service.dart';
    import "package:innovative_world/shared/decoration.dart";
    import 'package:innovative_world/shared/loading.dart';
    import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
    import "package:innovative_world/models/user_model.dart";
    import "package:innovative_world/models/list_model.dart";


    class Home extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
    }

    class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
      String _text;
      final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
      List<String> userDoc = [];


      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        final user = Provider.of<UserId>(context);

        return StreamBuilder<UserList>(
            stream: DatabaseService(uid: user.uid).userListStream,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                UserList userList = snapshot.data;
                // List<String> userDoc = [userList.list.toString()];
                return Scaffold(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.blue[200],
                  appBar: AppBar(
                    title: Text(
                      "Create List",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 23.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                    elevation: 0.0,
                    actions: <Widget>[
                      FlatButton.icon(
                        onPressed: () {
                          AuthService().signOut();
                        },
                        icon: Icon(Icons.person),
                        label: Text("Sign out"),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  body: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 25.0, 20.0, 0.0),
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Form(
                          key: _formKey,
                          child: Column(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              TextFormField(
                                validator: (val) =>
                                    val.isEmpty ? "Enter text" : null,
                                onChanged: (val) => setState(() => _text = val),
                                decoration: InputDecorationConst.copyWith(
                                    hintText: "Create List..."),
                              ),
                              RaisedButton(
                                onPressed: () async {
                                  if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                                    userDoc.add(_text);

                                    _formKey.currentState.reset();
                                    await DatabaseService(uid: user.uid)
                                        .setUserData(userDoc ?? userList.list);
                                  }
                                },
                                color: Colors.pink,
                                child: Text(
                                  "Add to list",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 15.0, color: Colors.white),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 15.0),
                        ListView.builder(
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemCount: userList.list.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return ForList(index: index, theList: userList.list);
                          },
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              } else {
                return Loading();
              }
            });
      }
    }

    class ForList extends StatefulWidget {
      final int index;
      final List<String> theList;

      ForList({this.index, this.theList});

      @override
      _ForListState createState() => _ForListState();
    }

    class _ForListState extends State<ForList> {
      bool isSelected = false;

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        final user = Provider.of<UserId>(context);

        return Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Card(
              child: CheckboxListTile(
                title: Text(widget.theList[widget.index]),
                value: isSelected,
                onChanged: (bool val)  {
                  setState(() {
                    isSelected = val;
                    if (isSelected) {
                    DatabaseService(uid: user.uid).deleteListArr(widget.index);
                    }
                  });
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        );
      }
    }
```

Right above is where I have a separate widget 'ForList' that holds the snapshot.data and the index, it all seems well to me, but I can't figure out why it won't remove the element from the db

Comment: It's hard to tell what your expect your code to do, since we can't see the underlying data that it expects to work on.  Please edit the question to show the data, and how you expect it to change after running a specific bit of code.  We should be able to track everything that's happening.  It might help if you read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason arrayRemove() was not working was because it was needing more than just the index, but also the string to which it correlated to.

#### Db service

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import "package:innovative_world/models/list_model.dart";

class DatabaseService {
  // Collection Reference
  CollectionReference listCollection = Firestore.instance.collection("list");

  // Get current users id
  final String uid;
  DatabaseService({this.uid});

  // Set data to firestore db
  Future setUserData(List<String> list) async {
    return await listCollection.document(uid).setData({ 
      "list": list
    });
  }

  // For deleting the lists
  Future deleteListArr(String index) async {
    return await listCollection.document(uid)
      .updateData({ "list": FieldValue.arrayRemove([index]) });
  }
  


  // UserList snapshot
  UserList _userListFromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    return UserList(
      uid: uid, 
      list: snapshot.data["list"].cast<String>().toList()
      ); 
  } 
  // Stream for user's to do list
  Stream<UserList> get userListStream {
    return listCollection.document(uid).snapshots()
      .map(_userListFromSnapshot);
  }
}
```

#### Home

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import "package:innovative_world/services/auth_service.dart";
import "package:innovative_world/models/list_model.dart";
import 'package:innovative_world/services/database_service.dart';
import "package:innovative_world/shared/decoration.dart";
import 'package:innovative_world/shared/loading.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import "package:innovative_world/models/user_model.dart";
import "package:innovative_world/models/list_model.dart";
import 'dart:async';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  String _text;
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  List<String> userDoc = [];
  // On every refresh the userDoc starts from 0, so it overrides the data

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<UserId>(context);

    return StreamBuilder<UserList>(
        stream: DatabaseService(uid: user.uid).userListStream,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            UserList userList = snapshot.data;
            // List<String> userDoc = [userList.list.toString()];
            return Scaffold(
              backgroundColor: Colors.blue[200],
              appBar: AppBar(
                title: Text(
                  "Create List",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 23.0,
                  ),
                ),
                elevation: 0.0,
                actions: <Widget>[
                  FlatButton.icon(
                    onPressed: () {
                      AuthService().signOut();
                    },
                    icon: Icon(Icons.person),
                    label: Text("Sign out"),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              body: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 25.0, 20.0, 0.0),
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Form(
                      key: _formKey,
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          TextFormField(
                            validator: (val) =>
                                val.isEmpty ? "Enter text" : null,
                            onChanged: (val) => setState(() => _text = val),
                            decoration: InputDecorationConst.copyWith(
                                hintText: "Create List..."),
                          ),
                          RaisedButton(
                            onPressed: () async {
                              if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                                userDoc.add(_text);
                                _formKey.currentState.reset();
                                await DatabaseService(uid: user.uid)
                                    .setUserData(userDoc ?? userList.list);
                              }
                            },
                            color: Colors.pink,
                            child: Text(
                              "Add to list",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 15.0, color: Colors.white),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 15.0),
                    ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: userList.list.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return ForList(listsIndex: userList.list[index], index: index, theList: userList.list);
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
          } else {
            return Loading();
          }
        });
  }
}

class ForList extends StatefulWidget {
  final int index;
  final String listsIndex;
  final List<String> theList;

  ForList({ this.listsIndex, this.index, this.theList });

  @override
  _ForListState createState() => _ForListState();
}

class _ForListState extends State<ForList> {
  bool isSelected = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<UserId>(context);

    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Card(
          child: CheckboxListTile(
            title: Text(widget.theList[widget.index]),
            value: isSelected,
            onChanged: (bool val) {
              setState(() {
                isSelected = val;
                Timer(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
                  setState(() async {
                  if (isSelected) {
                    await DatabaseService(uid: user.uid).deleteListArr(widget.listsIndex);
                   
                    }
                  });
                });
              });
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

I now added a new argument in the 'ForList' instance, 'listsIndex", which contains the string alongside the index.